# Implementing a custom LINQ-to-X provider

Tags: .net, linq

I've got a search tool which takes a complex search string (actually, an n-level object graph in JSON) and returns some results. I want to expose the functionality to other (internal) developers through a LINQ-like mechanism.

Assuming each result is defined by a class `Result`

I can create methods look something like:

```
Function Search(Expression As Linq.Expression(Of System.Func(Of Result, Boolean))) As IEnumerable(Of Result)
```

What I'm unclear of is how I can walk that `Expression` parameter and extract the actual criteria which I can then form into the object graph for running my query.

Can someone point me at a tutorial/example of how this can be achieved?

For a little background, I've managed to dig into the expression far enough to get the recursive structure and am able to examine the `.Body` of lambda expressions but when I get as far as wanting to handle the `Left` and `Right` properties of a Node with eg type `ExpressionType.Or`, I'm having issues. The debugger is using a Friend-scoped class (`BinaryExpressionProxy`) to examine the expression which isn't available to me so I'm clearly heading down the wrong route.

Comment: As you've asked it, this question is pretty broad. Is your question about how to navigate Expression Trees? There are plenty of tutorials around if you google them, but it looks like you've figured some of that out. Are you asking specifically about how to examine the `Left` and `Right` properties of a node? What specifically are you having difficulty with there?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior The honest answer is, I don't know - it's an unknown unknown. I've played with the creation side of queries for a few years now and think I've got an idea how they work. When trying to convert a query into something useful from the other side, the first issue I ran into was the `BinaryExpression`. Seeing as how there's a scoping issue, it indicated I was taking the wrong approach so really I was hoping for an introduction to the topic of evaluating expressions as a whole.

Comment: Since this question is vague, I'm going to vote to close it. Hopefully you will be able to read some of the tutorials out there and get an idea of what you don't know. When you can narrow your difficulties down to an answerable question, hopefully we can help you more.

Comment: If you Google "custom linq provider tutorial", http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252751 appears high in the results because it doesn't include a lot of information beyond that simple question. This makes it easier for other people to find answers to their questions quickly. The purpose of closing questions (as "Not a Real Question", "Exact Duplicate", etc.) is not to shut people down, but to maintain a high level of relevance on StackOverflow. I understand that there are other worse questions that haven't been closed; I don't go hunting for them, but I do vote to close them when I find them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to look at subclassing the [ExpressionVisitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) class. This provides the mechanism to walk the expression tree, all you have override the methods to process each type of node.

Here are some other links you may find helpful:

- Expression Tree Docs:

  - [VB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/)
  - [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/)
- [Expression Tree Basics (blog post)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/charlie/expression-tree-basics)

Answer (score 4):

You can try using a project I wrote called [LinqToAnything](https://github.com/mcintyre321/LinqToAnything) which you can use to wrap datasources to expose an IQueryable, depending on your needs.