# c# entity linq and linqpad differences

Tags: c#, linq, entity, linqpad

With a grouped query, when building by result I get different results

This works in LinqPad but not in code

```
Name = s.Key.FirstName + " " + s.Key.LastName ?? "Unknown User"
```

This works in Code but not in LinqPad

```
Name = s.Key.FirstName != null ? s.Key.LastName + " " + s.Key.LastName : "Unknown User"
```

This works in both

```
Name = String.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Key.FirstName) ? "Unknown User" : s.Key.FirstName + " " + s.Key.LastName,
```

Can anyone explain why

Comment: Is this hitting the database, or simply an in memory query? If it's hitting the database - LINQPad uses [Linq2Sql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx) - while your application is *likely* using entity framework.

Comment: Yes its using a database

Comment: Linqpad is no more than a tool for faster learning, right? so why not try microsofts' official one: [101 LINQ Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

Comment: @rob if you post that as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinqPad uses Linq2Sql by default.

The are certainly differences in the LINQ that works between `EF` and `Linq2Sql`. That is almost certainly what you are running into.

LINQ acts differently based on what provider actually runs the composed query.
There are many more than this but it's a start:

- Linq2Sql
- Entity Framework
- Linq to Objects
- Linq to Xml
- Linq to Events ([Reactive Extensions](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET))

You can write your own [LINQ providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181276/implementing-a-custom-linq-to-x-provider)

Although if you tell Linqpad to add an EF library it will consume one you create:

[image: adding an EF context to linqpad]